# Is it possible to set an image source on a javascript object property?

Tags: javascript, object

Take this piece of code into consideration:

```
var obj = {
  width : 10,
  height : 10,
  img : new Image(),
  img.src : "assets/img.png" // this is where I get an error
};
```

I get an error on `img.src`. Do I have to set the src afterwards or is there a workaround?

Comment: That syntax is invalid.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, you have to set it aftwards unless you want to wrap your `img` initialization in an [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately-invoked_function_expression):

```js
var obj = {
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
  img: (function() {
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUvWS.jpg";
    return img;
  })()
};

console.log("img src: %o", obj.img.src);
```

... or use `Object.assign()`:

```js
var obj = {
  width: 10,
  height: 10,
  img: Object.assign(new Image, {
    src: "https://i.stack.imgur.com/KUvWS.jpg"
  })
};

console.log("img src: %o", obj.img.src);
```